# Guardar canva de un formulario Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, canvas

Hola estoy realizando un formulario que tiene un canva donde la persona pueda hacer su firma, me pidieron que esta firma se guarde en el servidor y en base de datos como ruta. No se como realizar este proceso y agradecería vuestra ayuda.

Vista :

```html
<div class="img-centro">
    <img  class="" src="<?=base_url('img/').$img?>">
    <img class="right-move" src="<?=base_url('img/').$img2?>">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="loader"></div>

<div class="container ">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <br>
                <br>
                <form id="form-registry-cliente" class="form-horizontal forla-whith" role="form" method="post" action="<?=base_url('empleado/insertar')?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="prueba1">Nombre y Apellido</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control formu-width"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo set_value('nombre')?>"/>
                                <?=form_error('nombre', '<div class=" same-input alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" class="form-control formu-width"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Apellido" value="<?php echo set_value('apellidos')?>"/>
                                <?=form_error('apellidos', '<div class="same-input alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group prueba">
                        <label>E-mail</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control formu-width" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" value="<?php echo set_value('email')?>"/>
                        <?=form_error('email', '<div class="same-input alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group prueba">
                        <label>Ciudad</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" autocomplete="off" class="form-control formu-width" placeholder="Ciudad" value="<?php echo set_value('ciudad')?>"/>
                        <?=form_error('ciudad', '<div class="same-input alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hotel" name="hotel" readonly class="form-control"  value="<?= $nmhotel ?>"/>
                    <div class="" >
                        <select name="ubicacion" id="ubicacion" class="" style=" visibility: hidden ">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="sintonia" <?php if ($localizacion =='sintonio'){?> selected<?php } ?>>Sintonia</option>
                            <option value="the-top_gallery_hotel" <?php if ($localizacion =='top_gallery'){?> selected<?php } ?>>The Top GH</option>
                            <option value="Matiz" <?php if ($localizacion =='Matiz'){?> selected<?php } ?>>Matiz</option>
                            <option value="the_top_molina_lario" <?php if ($localizacion =='top_molina'){?> selected<?php } ?>>The Top ML</option>
                            <option value="Salicornia" <?php if ($localizacion =='Salicornia'){?> selected<?php } ?>>Salicornia</option>
                            <option value="the_top_honucai" <?php if ($localizacion =='top_honucai'){?> selected<?php } ?>>The Top HH</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group prueba">
                        <label>Firma</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group prueba" >
                        <canvas id="signature"  width="405" height="150" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;"></canvas> <!-- signature-->
                        <br>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary " id="clear-signature">Limpiar Firma</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-check prueba botton">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="terminos" id="terminos" value="acepta" data-toggle="modal">
                        <label class="form-check-label c-white" for="terminos">Acepto los términos y condiciones <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"style="color: red"></span></label>
                        <?=form_error('terminos', '<div class="alert alert-danger same-input">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hotel" name="hotel" value="<?= $hotel ?>"/>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <a class="btn btn-info prueba2" href=<?php echo base_url('principal')?>> <strong> < </strong> Volver</a>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-derecha" value="registrar">Guardar</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-warning derecha prueba3" href=<?php echo base_url('exportacion')?>> Reporting</a>
                        <input type='hidden' name='imagen' id='imagen' />

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Condiciones -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="politicaprivacidad" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aceptacion de condiciones" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color: black;font-weight: normal;">Política de privacidad   <span style="color: black;font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $nmhotel ?></span></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p style="color: black;line-height:25px;text-justify: auto;font-size: 1.2rem"><?php echo $condiciones ?> <a href="https://<?= $url ?>"> <?= $url ?></a> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        set_background();
     });

    function set_background(){
        var ubicacion = $('#ubicacion option:checked').val();
        var clase = '';

        switch (ubicacion){
            case 'sintonia':
                clase = 'gh-sintonia';
              break;
            case 'the-top_gallery_hotel':
                clase = 'gh-top';
              break;
            case 'Matiz':
                clase = 'molinala-matiz';
                break;
            case 'the_top_molina_lario':
                clase = 'molinala-top';
                break;
            case 'Salicornia':
                clase = 'hh-salicornia';
                break;
            case 'the_top_honucai':
                clase = 'hh-top';
                break;
            default:
                clase = 'gh-sintonia';
        }
        $('.container').addClass(clase);
    }

     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         var canvas = document.getElementById("signature");
         var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
         var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        $('#clear-signature').on('click', function(){
            signaturePad.clear();
        });

   });

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            $('#politicaprivacidad').modal();
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST";

    });

//    function saveImage() {
//        var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
//        var xmlHttpReq = false;
//        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
//            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
//        }
//        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
//            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
//        }
//        ajax.open('POST', '<?//=base_url('empleado/insertar')?>//', false);
//        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
//        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
//            console.log(ajax.responseText);
//        };
//        ajax.send("imgData="+canvasData);
//    }

//    function saveCanva(){
//
//        var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
//        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
//        ajax.open("POST",'<?//=base_url('empleado/insertar')?>//',false);
//        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
//            console.log(ajax.responseText);
//        };
//        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
//        ajax.send("imgData="+canvasData);
//    }
//    function guardar(){
//        var link = document.createElement('a');
//        link.download = "firma";
//
//        link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
//        link.click();
//    }
</script>
```

Jquery donde da las funciones al canva

```html
  function UploadPic(){
    // generamos los datos de la imagen
    var pic = document.getElementById("signature").toDataURL("img/png");
    // quitamos la "cabecera" de la imagen pues no la necesitamos
    pic = pic.replace(/^data:img\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

    // Enviamos los datos de la imagen al servidor
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: base_url + 'Empleado/saveimage',
        data: {imageData: pic},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            alert("Imagen almacenada.");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
public function insertar()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre','nombre','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('apellidos','apellido','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ciudad','ciudad','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ubicacion','ubicación','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('terminos','terminos','callback_terminos');


        $hotel = $this->session->userdata('hotel');
        $localizacion = $this->session->userdata('localizacion');


        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
            $datos['nombre']=set_value('nombre');
            $datos['apellidos']=set_value('apellidos');
            $datos['email']=set_value('email');
            $datos['ciudad']=set_value('ciudad');
            $datos['ubicacion']=set_value('ubicacion');
            $datos['terminos']=set_value('terminos');


            switch($hotel) {
                case 'barcelona':
                    $img='gh-head-logo.png';
                    $nmhotel='Gallery Hoteles';
                    break;
                case 'malaga':
                    $img='ml-head-logo.png';
                    $nmhotel='Hotel Molina Lario';
                    break;
                case 'mallorca':
                    $img='hh-head-logo.jpeg';
                    $nmhotel='Hotel Honucai';
                    break;
                default:
                    $img='hh-head-logo.png';
                    $nmhotel='';
            }

            switch($localizacion){
                case 'sintonio':
                    $img2 = 'gh-modal.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'top_gallery':
                    $img2 = 'modal-top-gh.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'Matiz':
                    $img2 = 'modal-resta-ml.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'top_molina':
                    $img2 = 'modal-top-ml.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'Salicornia':
                    $img2 = 'salicor-resta.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Asimismo, nos autoriza a que sus datos personales sean cedidos a la empresa del grupo GALLERY CENTER, S.L. (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona), con idénticas finalidades.
                                    Adicionalmente, únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. por escrito (C/ Gabriel Roca s/n, 07638, Colonia de Sant Jordi, Mallorca - Illes Balears) o por e-mail a galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com.
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.hotelhonucai.com/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'top_honucai';
                    $img2 = 'modal-top-honu.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Asimismo, nos autoriza a que sus datos personales sean cedidos a la empresa del grupo GALLERY CENTER, S.L. (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona), con idénticas finalidades.
                                    Adicionalmente, únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. por escrito (C/ Gabriel Roca s/n, 07638, Colonia de Sant Jordi, Mallorca - Illes Balears) o por e-mail a galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com.
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.hotelhonucai.com/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                default:
                    $img2 = 'gh-modal.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
            }

            $data['title']='Gallery Hoteles';
            $data['img']=$img;
            $data['nmhotel']=$nmhotel;
            $data['hotel']= $hotel;
            $data['img2']= $img2;
            $data['localizacion']= $localizacion;
            $data['condiciones']= $condiciones;
            $data['url']= $url;
            $this->load->view('comun/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('formulario/formu_views',$datos,$data);
            $this->load->view('comun/footer',$data);

        }else{
            $firma= str_replace(" ", "_", $this->input->post('nombre')).'_'.str_replace(" ", "_", $this->input->post('apellidos')).'_'.date('Y-m-d-H:i:s').'.png';
            $data = array(
                'nombre' =>$this->input->post('nombre'),
                'apellidos'=>$this->input->post('apellidos'),
                'email'=> $this->input->post('email'),
                'ciudad'=> $this->input->post('ciudad'),
                'fecha'=> date('Y-m-d  H:i:s'),
                'condiciones'=> 1,
                'firma'=>$firma,
                'ubicacion'=>$this->input->post('ubicacion'),
                'hotel'=>$this->input->post('hotel')
            );
            /* MAILCHIMP */

            $list_id = '0f61ec2abc';//EL HOTEL DEBERA PONER EL LIST ID DONDE GUARDARA LOS MAILS AL IGUAL QUE EM EL CONFIG LINEA 525
            $MailChimp = new MailChimp('APIKEY-us12');
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
                $this->mailchimp->verify_ssl = false;
            }
            $result = $this->mailchimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'merge_fields'  => [
                    'FNAME' =>$this->input->post('nombre'),
                    'LNAME'=>$this->input->post('apellidos'),
                    'CIUDAD'=>$this->input->post('ciudad'),
                    'UBICACION'=>$this->input->post('ubicacion'),
                    'NMHOTEL'=>$this->input->post('hotel'),
                ],
                    'status'=> 'subscribed',
            ]);

            $parametros = $_REQUEST;

            if ($parametros['imageData']) {
                $imgData = base64_decode($parametros['imageData']);
                $uniqid = uniqid();

                $imageFilePath = 'myImage_' . $uniqid . '.png';
                // Borro la imagen por si ya existía
                if (file_exists($imageFilePath)) {
                    unlink($imageFilePath);
                }
                // Escribo los datos en disco
                $file = fopen($imageFilePath, 'w');
                fclose($file);
            }

            $this->empleado_model->insertar($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('hotel',$hotel);
            redirect('empleado');
        }
```

Codigo donde llama al ajax lo he puesto en una funcion  donde inserta los datos en base de datos por que quiero que al momento que se a guardar se inserte los datos y a la vez de guardo en la carpeta que tengo en el servidor. Si hay algo que esta mal decidme porfavor. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de como almacenar el `canvas` en disco podría ser así:

**JAVASCRIPT** (en la pagina del formulario):

```
function UploadPic() {
    // generamos los datos de la imagen
    var pic = document.getElementById("fondoCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    // quitamos la "cabecera" de la imagen pues no la necesitamos
    pic = pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

    // Enviamos los datos de la imagen al servidor
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'guarda_imagen.php',
        data: {imageData: pic},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            alert("Imagen almacenada.");
        }
    });
}
```

La imagen de la firma está en un contenedor con `id="fondoCanvas"`, uso el método [`.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) para obtener la imagen codificada en base64.

**PHP** (recibe los datos del ajax y almacena la imagen):

```
<?php
$parametros = $_REQUEST;

if ($parametros['imageData']) {
    $imgData = base64_decode($parametros['imageData']);

    $uniqid = uniqid();
    $imageFilePath = 'myImage_' . $uniqid . '.png';

    // Borro la imagen por si ya existía
    if (file_exists($imageFilePath)) {
        unlink($imageFilePath);
    }

    // Escribo los datos en disco
    $file = fopen($imageFilePath, 'w');
    fclose($file);
}
```

Decodificamos la imagen y la almacenamos en el servidor, aquí se establecería el nombre y la ruta, que después se podría almacenar en base de datos.

> En este ejemplo solo se envían los datos de la imagen, pero se podría
>   enviar el resto de campos necesarios de un formulario.
>
> Enviar los datos por `ajax` es una opción, se podría enviar un
>   formulario POST normal, para lo cual bastaría con enviar los datos de
>   la imagen mediante un campo `hidden`.

Comment: Muchas gracias,tengo una duda en la url del ajax pondría el controlador, ya que estoy trabajando con codeigniter.Es correcto o no?.Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: No me ha funcionado, algo debo estar haciendo mal

Comment: Edita la pregunta añadiendo la nueva información o abre otra pregunta si el problema es diferente.

Comment: Listo, he puesto todo el codigo de la funcion insertar del controlador porque en el else hace la inserción en la database. Mil gracias.